# How to execute an http request when a link is clicked, modify the href, then follow the href

Tags: javascript, html

The following piece of code allows us to modify an `a` element's href prior to following it:

```
<a href="/initial-link" onclick="modifyHref($event)" />

<script>
    function modifyHref(event)
    {
        event.target.href = "/different-link";
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

I would like to achieve the above behaviour, but execute an http request in the onclick handler instead.

For example:

```
<script>
    function modifyHref(event)
    {
        httpClient.get('/my-data')
            .then(function(response) {
                event.target.href = "/different-link?id=" + response.data;
            });
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that the http GET request is asynchronous. The link's original href is followed prior to completion of the http request.

Note that I do *not* want to redirect the user with document.location.href. I want to use the `a` element's href to let the user navigate.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe you'd want to change your click event to look like `onclick="modifyHref(this)"`, since we don't care much about the *event* but rather the element it's actually acting on.

Next, the `onclick` fires `before` the anchor, but you need to prevent the default behaviour of then navigating, by returning `false` from your click handler.

```
    function modifyHref(a) {
      a.href = "https://www.google.com";
      return false;
    }
```

If you check out this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sid-kliw7?file=/index.html) you'll see that it actually goes to Google (ignoring the x-frame issue) instead of the original "initial-link".

Comment: Also I should add, its probably not very efficient to modify the link on demand, perhaps it would be better to run that logic when your page mounts, targeting the `id` of the anchor tag and swapping. This will guard against any failures, and will make the user experience stable, as the fetch trip is limited by the users internet connection.